# Как использовать кнопку в reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Мне надо сделать кнопку с функцией при нажатии

Но функции не вызывается при нажатии

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function Abc() {
...
}
```

ошибка :

```
    "message": "'Abc' is defined but never used.",
```

если поместить в app.js вылезает таже ошибка

app.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <header className="App-header">


          ....          
          <input type="button" onclick="Abc()" value="calculate"></input>
          ....




        
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

[image: Структура]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `onClick`, а не `onсlick`
2. Навешивать функцию нужно таким образом: `onClick={abc}`, а не таким: `onclick="Abc()"`
3. Функцию нужно объявлять в том компоненте, в котором собираетесь использовать, или же передавать ее в пропсах. Если коротко - вы не там объявили функцию

P.S. В `index.js` удалите `function Abc()...`, там это не нужно

```js
function App() {
  function abc() {
    console.log("abc");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <input type="button" onClick={abc} value="calculate"></input>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```